# Windows search query for a *part* of a word/substring in file contents

Tags: c#, sql, search, oledb, windows-search

I am trying to query the Windows Search index programmatically using the [Windows Search SQL Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231256(v=vs.85).aspx)

I am able to search **file contents** in my C# winforms application using the search query below:

```
string strSearchQuery =
    "SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
    "WHERE scope ='file:" + @"C:\myfolder\" + 
    "' and FREETEXT('dummy')";
```

**ISSUE:** However, I am *not* able to use this query to search for **part of a word** in the file contents.

For example: If a file (such as a .txt file) contains the the text "abcd", and I search for `FREETEXT('ab')`, it doesn't show that file.

I have tried using:

- `FREETEXT('ab')`
- `FREETEXT('*ab*')`
- `FREETEXT('\"ab\"')`
- `FREETEXT('\"*ab*\"')`
- `FREETEXT('*\"ab\"*')`
- `FREETEXT('ab*')`
- `FREETEXT('\"*ab*\"')`
- `FREETEXT('\"ab\"*')`

I've also tried using `CONTAINS` with the above combinations instead of `FREETEXT`.

When I search for `ab` directly on Windows search, it shows the file having the text

How can I modify this query to search for a part of a word in the file contents? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

FREETEXT() does not support wild cards. Use CONTAINS() instead.

```
string query = 
   "SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemUrl FROM SystemIndex " +
   "WHERE scope ='file:D:\MyFolder' and CONTAINS('\"dumm*\"')";
```

Note that the partial word you want to search on must be contained within double quotes, along with the wildcard * character.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard character  is the `%`, so your query should look like this :

```
string strSearchQuery =
    "SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
    "WHERE scope ='file:" + @"C:\myfolder\" + 
    "' and FREETEXT(%'dummy'%)";
```

EDIT :

```
 string strSearchQuery =
        "SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
        "WHERE scope ='file:" + @"C:\myfolder\" + 
        "' and FREETEXT('%dummy%')";
```

Comment: When I use `FREETEXT(%'dummy'%)`, I get a `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException`

Comment: have a look at my edit , now it should work. i miseplaced the order of % and '

Comment: Using it in that order - `FREETEXT('%dummy%')` - does not return any results for part of a word :(

Comment: do you have files named dummy in your c:\myfolder\ location ?

Comment: yes. i do have a txt file that contains the text `aaadummyaaa` in that folder. And if i do a search directly using windows explorer, for `dummy` it shows this file

Comment: try using CONTAINS instead of FREETEXT, with * instead of %

Comment: i just tried that. still no results for part of a word :/

Comment: try this Contains('\"*dummy*\"')

Comment: that doesn't work if the file contains `aaadummyaaa` and i search for `dummy`. that works only if i search for `aaadummy`. i.e. word prefix

Comment: look here to twek the expressions to meet your needs ,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231270(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i did look at that. it says that the `CONTAINS` predicate can only be used with a wildcard at the end :/ Not sure how to mimic the windows explorer functionality so that it can search anywhere within a word

Answer (score 0):

There's a COP_VALUE_CONTAINS operator. The SQL symbol is ~= or ~~.
E.g.  System.FullText :~="abc".